# Определить ОС в C++

Tags: c++

Как можно определить ОС в функции С++?

т.е. есть функция (допустим echod) и если ОС Windows, то выполнять допустим a = 1+1, а если Linux, то a = 2+2?

Comment: прогуглите, на форумах легко найдете
http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=294285

Comment: На скок я видел обыно эта штука делается через define' ы, например

    #ifdef __WIN32__
      <code for win>
    #else
      <code for other>
    #endif

и в аналогичном духе, соответвенно внутри функции оборачиваешь все в дефайны. Аналоги можно посмотреть в какомнибудь boost'е или Qt


Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартными средствами - боюсь, что никак. Но можно исхитриться. Для начала можно вспомнить, что для разных определенных операционных систем придется программу пересобирать и тут уже сама разработки предлагает различные макросы для определения, на какой платформе будет выполняться программа. Если же требуется определять тип операционной системы не во время компиляции, а в рантайме, то придется серьезно думать, т.к. отличия есть, но возможно придется использовать сторонние библиотеки или использовать ассемблерные вставки (напр, для системных вызовов). Из не очень переносимых способов могу упомянуть использование переменных окружения. Функция `getenv()`, предназначенная для работы с ними, есть в любом с++, поэтому можно сделать некую эвристику. Например:

```
char* ostype = getenv("OSTYPE");
if (ostype == NULL)
{
   // не угадали. попробуем, а вдруг это виндовс!?
   ostype = getenv("windir");
   if (ostype != NULL)
   { printf ("windows catalog is found!!! yo!");}
}
else
{
   // переменная окружения есть, попробуем вызнать что же это такое.
   if(strcmp(ostype, "linux") == 0)
      printf("linux");
   else if(strcmp(ostype, "hpux") == 0)
      printf("hpux");
   else if(strcmp(ostype, "solaris") == 0)
      printf("solaris");
   else if(strcmp(ostype, "darwin") == 0)
      printf("darwin");
}
```

В любом случае, я такой код не рекомендую. Я вообще не рекомендую забиваться на тип операционной системы, тем более, что его не проблема подменить. Чего уж стоит запуск win32 программ через wine на linux. Главное понимать какие Вам нужны функции, которые могут на определенной платформе отсутствовать. А это, во-первых, уже другая задача. А, во-вторых, ее можно решить более грамотными способами (напр., под Windows запросто можно использовать вызовы `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` для определения того есть ли нужная библиотека и нужная ф-ция в ней).

Comment: я работаю над темой "Кроссплатформерное программирование", а именно пишу уникальную функцию для вывода русского шрифта во всех ОС. Сейчас попытаюсь проверить ваш код

Comment: В итоге обошёлся #ifdef, но всё равно спасибо за старание

Comment: Наверное лучше всего воспользоваться либо системным вызовом `uname`, либо разбором вывода команды `uname -a` (в винде команда `ver`).

В Линуксах кое-что можно вытянуть из файла /etc/issue.

При анализе environment проверка на имя `_` показывает, что программа запущена из sh/bash и т.п. 

(В этой переменной содержится последняя выполненная шеллом команда).

Это знание может оказаться полезным (например, при генерации в программе команд и выполнении их через system/popen).

Не знаю, как у @gecube, а в доступных мне Линуксах переменной ostype (OSTYPE) нет.

Comment: @avp, 

    declare -x MACHTYPE="x86_64-suse-linux"
    declare -x MAIL="/var/spool/mail/gaal"
    declare -x MANPATH="/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man"
    declare -x MINICOM="-c on"
    declare -x MORE="-sl"
    declare -x NNTPSERVER="news"
    declare -x OLDPWD
    declare -x OSTYPE="linux"

> uname -a (в винде команда ver).

+100!

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в таких случая делается платформенно заисимый #define в опциях компилятора
например (то что я встречал): 
-DWIN32
-DWIN64
-D**linux**
-D**darwin**
-D**i386**
**amd64**
**sparc**
**powerpc**
итд

А в целом надо ориентироваться на спецификацию POSIX если пишете под Unix-подобные системы, и писать отдельный код для Windows, разрешая его компиляцию через #ifdef. Но бывают случаи разные. Ингода приходилось под конкретный юникс писать отдельный код.